# Allow AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer preview rotate with device

Tags: swift, xcode, avcapturesession

I have a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` in my app, and it works fine on devices in portrait, but in landscape, the video is sideways.
I tried

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .all
}
```

But the issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it - I just had to add this-

```
    if UIDevice.current.orientation == .portrait {
        previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
    } else if UIDevice.current.orientation == .portraitUpsideDown {
        previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .portraitUpsideDown
    } else if UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeLeft {
        previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
    } else if UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeRight {
        previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .landscapeLeft
    }
```

-which gets called when the device is rotated. I also call it on startup after I have initialized the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`.